# JQuery onclick display Textbox Value in Paragraph Text

Tags: jquery, events

I want to display the Value from textbox in Paragraph Text. 
My P tags have unique IDs in the form of Data attr. Upon clicking a button i only want to update the text whose button belongs to that ID.
I tried but all of the Paragraph text is getting updated.

**Paragraph HTML:**

```
<div class="facilityContent">
<p data-levelid="1" data-locationid="1">This is an example of a multi-line ellipsis.This is an example of a multi-line ellipsisThis is an example of a multi-line ellipsisThis is an example of a multi-line ellipsisThis is an example of a multi-line ellipsis</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="editbtn">Edit</a>
</div>
```

**Button HTML**

```
<div class="facilityContentBox" style="display: block;">
    <p>Facility Name</p>
    <input type="text" id="txtFacility1" class="facilityInputBox" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="facilityBtnBox">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cancelEdit pull-left">Cancel</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default pull-right facilitySaveBtn">Save</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".facilitySaveBtn").click(function(){
    //debugger
        // alert("Clicked");
        var facilityInput = $(this).parent().siblings('input').val();
        var selectedInputId = $(this).parent().parent().siblings(".departmentContent").find("p").attr("data-locationid");
        //debugger
        $(".facilityContentBox").hide();
        $(".facilityContent").show();
        $(".editbtn").show();
        if (selectedInputId !== undefined) {
            $("p" + selectedInputId).text(facilityInput);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the value for "data-locationid" selected, use that id value in the `<p>` selector

replace this

```
$("p" + selectedInputId).text(facilityInput);
```

--> in your case `$("p" + selectedInputId)` return p1 tag for example

to

```
$('p[data-locationid='+selectedInputId+']' ).text(facilityInput);
```

Answer (score 2):

p1 tag (p + selectedInputId) is not exist . That's why your code not work.

You must change:

```
$("p" + selectedInputId).text(facilityInput);
```

To:

```
$("p[data-locationid="+selectedInputId+"]").text(facilityInput);
```